# How can two concurrent threads or processes communicate?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency

Broadly, how does inter-process and inter-thread communication work?

Clarification: I understand this question can't be exhaustively answered in one succinct paragraph.  I'm looking for answers that will be a good starting point for beginners - high level concepts of how it works.

Comment: This question has a lot of answers depending on which system you're talking about. Are you talking about Win32, pthreads, Erlang, MPI, Linda spaces, or what?

Comment: Are you expecting a treatise?  This is a very broad question.

Comment: I'm looking for a high level answer to help beginners to explore more on the topic

Comment: @philfreo, do you mean that you do not personally care about the answer but, wikipedia-style, are trying to expand on the body of content at SO?  IMO, that's disingenuous.

Comment: I do care about the answer... what's the problem? I'm trying to learn myself as well as help others.  I don't have a particular system or piece of code in mind, just trying to learn more...

Comment: All of the knowledge is covered in a college-level CS course called Operating Systems. http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~cs537-1/

Comment: Is it really impossible to explain some of it at a high level? Isn't SO supposed to be a non-threatening environment to help people learn new things about programming?

Comment: @philfreo: Think of it as asking a busy secretary to do some work. You write down your request in a memo note, and stick it to the document which you want the secretary to process, and put the document in the secretary's In Tray. The secretary will pick some task from the In Tray (based on priority or first-come-first-serve or easiest-task-first), and then start processing it. When the secretary finish processing the document will be put in the Out Tray. You'll need to watch the Out Tray in order to know that your request has been completed.

Comment: @philfreo: the high level concept is called [message passing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_passing). However, real programmers use a lot of machine-level shortcuts (shared memory) to avoid the overhead associated with true message passing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Broadly, there are two basic mechanisms.

The simplest is shared memory.  Both processes have access to some memory that can be used read or write, such that writes in one are visible in the reads of the other.

The other mechanism is channels, which acts like a pipe between the two processes.  In this case, one process puts some data into the pipe, and the other process pulls it out.  This mechanism is destructive, once consumed, the data is lost from the pipes, so the receiving process better do something with it.

Although the first case sounds simpler, in practice it is wrought with peril.  If both processes try to write at the same time, who knows what will happen.  To avoid that, a third type of IPC mechanism is used, locks, which are used to signal from one process to the other when it's ok to do something to the shared state.

From a theoretical point of view, they are all equivalent.  Most operating systems provide all of these mechanisms.

But concurrent processes do not have to communicate.  in the "Shared Nothing" Model, a single master task prepares a number of work tasks.  The work tasks perform a calculation without additional input.  when all of the workers are done, the master task can produce a result.  This is attractive because IPC comes with a perfomance cost (synchronization), and shared nothing sidesteps synchronization entirely.

Comment: There is also a type of concurrent programming that *do not* communicate (except before the task starts and after the task ends), such as map-reduce.

Answer (score 2):

inter-processes: between processes - boardly, System 5 IPC. specifically, it would encompass pipes, semaphores, shared memory, sockets, signals. Typically, these services are provided by the OS kernel

inter-thread: communication between the threads of the same process. you would use thread-synchronization primitives - which could provided by the OS, and it also be implemented in the user space thread-library.